# How to fit all pages of a PDF file in Indesign using python?

Tags: python, pdf, adobe-indesign, extendscript

Internet searches have yielded the following results:

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch('InDesign.Application')


myFile = r'C:\test.indd'
myDocument = app.Open(myFile)
myPage = myDocument.Pages.Item(1)


for x in range(0, 5):
    myPage = myDocument.Pages.Add()

for a in range(0,5):
    myPage = myDocument.Pages.Item(a + 1)
    myRectangle = myPage.Rectangles.Add()
    myRectangle.GeometricBounds = ["0", "0", "297mm", "210mm"]
    myRectangle.StrokeWeight = 0
    myPlace = myRectangle.Place(r'C:\mail.pdf')
```

All I have to do is make sure that pages from the PDF file (for example, 1-20 pages) are placed on each separate page in Indesign. I found this code on the adobe indesign site, but I can't think of it to the end... An error pops up that such a variable does not exist (myPage.PDFPlacePreference.PageNumber = "2").

```
myPage.PDFPlacePreference.PageNumber = "2"
myPlacePDFFile = myPage.Place(r'C:\mail.pdf')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
myPage.PDFPlacePreference.PageNumber = "2"
```

with:

```
app.PDFPlacePreferences.PageNumber = 2
```